# Facebook JavaScript SDK Login Button Doesn't Pop Up Permission

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, button, authentication

I've been using the code below for a long time for many facebook apps that I created, but since a few hours ago this code does not seem to work anymore. I do not know if this code can no longer be used or temporarily unusable. Is there any alternative code that is similar to the code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>FB APP</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
    background: #ffffff url('lp.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    margin-left: 160px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:fabada;
    src: url('fabada.ttf');
}
#likegate{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- DEFINITING FACEBOOK APP ID -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId   : '448829841800709',
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.UIServer.setActiveNode = function(a,b){FB.UIServer._active[a.id]=b;}
    // Scroll Bar Fixed
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(90);
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 555 });
    }, 250);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loging(getuid){
jQuery("#loginfb").hide();
jQuery("#fbload").show();
FB.api(
          {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid=' + getuid 
          },
          function(response) {
            var user = response[0];
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'login.php?uid=' + getuid,
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#jstarget').html(data);
                jQuery("#fbload").hide();
            }
            });
          }
        );        
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.init({
          appId   : '448829841800709',
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
          oauth   : true
        });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // fetch the status on load
    jQuery('#loginfb').bind('click', function() {
        FB.init({
              appId   : '448829841800709',
              status  : true, // check login status
              cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
              oauth   : true
            });
        if (response.authResponse){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            loging(response.id);
            }); 
        } 
        else{
            //user is not connected to your app or logged out
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    loging(response.id);
                    });
                } 
                else {
                    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                }
            }, {scope:'publish_stream'});   
        }
    });
    // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
});
</script>
<div id="jstarget"></div>

<div id="box">
    <!--MAIN CONTENT-->
    <div id="content">
        <div id="likegate">
            <img src="login.png" style="cursor: pointer; float: left;" id="loginfb" alt="Login">
            <img src="ajax-loader.gif" style="float: left; padding-left: 50px; display:none" id="fbload" alt="Loading">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

When I remove this

```
if (response.authResponse){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    loging(response.id);
    }); 
}
else{
   // this code here not removed
}
```

it show pop up permission dialog, but when I've allow this app, then I click login button again, why it show pop up permission dialog again?

Comment: Why do you have **3** *Fb.init* calls?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove all the multiple FB.init, dont use .bind() after jquery 1.7.1 it will be depreciated sub that with .on()

2) add channel.html that should help you with any XD issue.
3) use FB.getAuthResponse() , to get authentication response

i did a quick clean up but never tested! and there is a lot of room for improvment here is what it looks like:

```
<!-- DEFINITING FACEBOOK APP ID -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '448829841800709', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

     FB.UIServer.setActiveNode = function(a,b){FB.UIServer._active[a.id]=b;}
    // Scroll Bar Fixed
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(90);
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 555 });
    }, 250);

  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loging(getuid){
    jQuery("#loginfb").hide();
    jQuery("#fbload").show();
    FB.api(
              {
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid=' + getuid 
              },
              function(response) {
                var user = response[0];
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'login.php?uid=' + getuid,
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#jstarget').html(data);
                    jQuery("#fbload").hide();
                }
                });
              }
            );        
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // fetch the status on load
    jQuery('#loginfb').on('click', function() {

        if (FB.getAuthResponse()){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            loging(response.id);
            }); 
        } 
        else{
            //user is not connected to your app or logged out
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    loging(response.id);
                    });
                } 
                else {
                    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                }
            }, {scope:'publish_stream'});   
        }
    });
    // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
});
</script>
```

Comment: @RiyantoWibowo welcome to SO! if you think that this answer was helpful, you have to select it as the correct one. 
Also take a look at the SO FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq